# What is the correct way to transform a model variable to use NgRx state?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I'm trying to convert my Ionic app to NgRx.

In one of my components I have a model variable that connects to a textarea like this:

component:

```
myTextVar: string = '';
```

template:

```
<ion-textarea ... [(ngModel)]="myTextVar" ...></ion-textarea>
```

So, trying to convert this to NgRx I created a field in the module reducer:

```
const textsFeatureKey = 'texts';

export interface TextsState {
    ...
    myTextVar: string;
}

export const initialState: TextsState = {
    ...
    myTextVar: '',
};

export const textsReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    ...
    on(TextsActions.setMyTextVar, (state, { myTextVar }) => ({ ...state, myTextVar })),
);
```

an action:

```
export const setMyTextVar = createAction('[Texts Page] Set myTextVar', props<{ myTextVar: string }>());
```

and a selector:

```
export const selectMyTextVar = (state: AppState) => state.texts.myTextVar;
```

Then in the component I changed this:

```
myTextVar$: Observable<string>;

constructor(
    private store: Store<{ texts: any; }>
) {
    ...
    this.myTextVar$ = this.store.select(selectMyTextVar)
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.myTextVar$.subscribe(text => {
        console.log('mtv debug', text);
    })
    this.store.dispatch(setMyTextVar({ myTextVar: 'some initial text'}));
    ...
}
```

So far so good... it loaded myTextVar in the textarea when I do it like this:

```
<ion-textarea [ngModel]="myTextVar$ | async" ></ion-textarea>
```

but now... How do I update the state ? I have done it like this:

```
<ion-textarea (ionInput)="onIonInputMyTextVar($event)" [ngModel]="myTextVar$ | async" ></ion-textarea>
```

and then in the component:

```
onIonInputMyTextVar(event: any) {
    this.store.dispatch(setMyTextVar({ myTextVar: event.detail.value }));
}
```

This works. But isn't this too far fetched to just update a model var ? I have substituted 2 lines of code by a much larger and harder to maintain code having to handle ionInput event, reducer, selector, initialization, several selects along the code...

Makes me think I'm doing something wrong. Maybe there is a simpler way to convert ngModel vars or simply I shouldn't be using NgRx to handle simple variables cases in the component.

So my questions are:

1. Am I doing this right ? Is there a simpler way to convert ngModel vars ?
2. Should I really be doing this ? Isn't traditional `[(ngModel)]='myTextVar'` much cleaner for simple cases like this ?
3. This is a simple single component var. Where should NgRx really be used ? Should I use it only for multi-component data ?

Comment: the ngModel scope is only the component itself, by using NgRx you make the scope of the store be as long as you want, therefore all components can interact with this state and all changes in the state will be reflected in the components where it is used. You miss an unsubscription in your code when you manually subscribe then you have to unsubscribe in the OnDestroy, the async pipe removes that need and handles it authomatically

Comment: But that's the point. It's a single component var. Should I be using it in this case ?
Also about the subscription, I created it for debug only to see if the field is being updated correctly. But how do you think it's the correct way to unsubscribe it in OnDestroy ?

Comment: The correct way I think is using the async pipe only, getting rid of extra subscriptions/unsuscriptions. You take the value from the store using the async pipe, in all cases you can apply operators to the Observable and use the async pipe over the mutated observable

Comment: Also, it's important to understand the scope of each store, you might have a piece of store that is loaded in the root and used throught the entire codebase, or you could have a lazy loaded piece of store that its only scope is a specific module. NgRx allows you to customize your store as you see fit. If i was to combine NgRx with something else it would be Signals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused because you missed one very important thing about NGRX store: it is used for **global** state management. "global" means at least on the module level.

> But isn't this too far fetched to just update a model var ? I have substituted 2 lines of code by a much larger and harder to maintain code having to handle ionInput event, reducer, selector, initialization, several selects along the code

It looks like it is in your case. First of all, your component looks like a "dumb component", which means it shouldn't access external services at all. Secondly, the value produced by the component is not used anywhere, this means it shouldn't be in the global state. Thirdly, NGRX was created for large apps, not for any kind of tiny two-components-large side projects.

Before you decide to use any kind of state management library in future think about the data flow:

1. If you collect some information in the component, immediately push it to the server and don't use this information or its derivatives elsewhere in the app, you don't need any kind of state
2. If you collect some information in the component, immediately push it to the server and use this information or its derivatives in the [smart] component directly, you need a component store
3. If you collect some information in the component, immediately push it to the server and use this information or its derivatives in other **not related** components or modules, you need an application-wide store

*Of course, there are certain exceptions but this is a different topic.*

BTW, it is also okay if in the project where NGRX is used some of the components don't use NGRX. You don't have to always push every bit of information in the global state.

Comment: Thanks. I was reaching the same conclusion, but as I'm still learning state management, I was insecure of where exactly to use. One thing that contributed to my confusion was the initial examples in NgRx. People use it to create an increment/decrement variable. This made it look I should use it for all vars. I also thought that as every successful software tends only to grow I should adopt it from the beggining even if it's still small.
Let's see if more people has some contributions to this topic. But my inclination now is to use it only when more than 1 component is involved.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira that's the problem: you can't create complex examples because (1) it takes lots of time and (2) beginners won;t understand it. But at the same time beginners are often confused by those simple examples. I would add to your rule "... when more than 1 *smart* component *from different routing tree/hierarchy* is involved"

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Please watch this video about common NGRX pitfalls https://www.youtube.com/live/JP4dEM4bjE8?si=IbYCo4E13zpG0VQQ it is really long but totally worth your time